# Is there a way to have NPM CLI use custom protocols?

Tags: git, protocols, npm-install, aws-sso, npm-cli

Is there a way to have `npm CLI` to use custom protocols?

```
...
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "common-resource-1": "git+codecommit::us-east-1://common-resource-1#develop",
    "common-resource-2": "git+codecommit://common-resource-1#develop",
   ...
}
...
```

Any of the two would suffice.

This is for use with `AWS SSO`, codecommit and repos cloned using `GRC` links.  For more info see this question:
[AWS SSO, Codecommit (GRC git clone link) and npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73719716/aws-sso-codecommit-grc-git-clone-link-and-npm-install)

To be clear this is not a git issue as part of the `AWS SSO` setup is installing a python package called `git-remote-codecommit` that allows git to recognize the codecommit protocol.  However, npm cli does not recognize codecommit protocol as a valid protocol to use when trying to retrieve dependencies.

Running the command `npm install` fails with the following error:

```
npm ERR! code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type "git+codecommit:": git+codecommit::us-east-1://some-repo
```

or

```
npm ERR! code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type "git+codecommit:": git+codecommit://some-repo
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please ask clear, specific questions in your titles. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If on a mac:

1. Remove any keychains entries that may pertain to the domain and/or repository in question. This was my main problem.
2. Use the git credential-helper with aws command as followings:

   ```
   [credential "https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"]
        UseHttpPath = true
        helper = !aws codecommit credential-helper $@
   ```

Note: if on mac and it still does not work, may have to add dummy value for the username attribute.

```
[credential "https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"]
     UseHttpPath = true
     helper = !aws codecommit credential-helper $@
     username = "dummy"
```

Comment: No need for the meta-commentary. _Every_ answer is posted assuming better ones may come along.